# How to get rid of / minify Photohop Layer Styles in Layers List?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, layer-style

I use Layer Styles a lot, unfortunately with bigger projects it's really annoying that they take so much space in Layers list (even if their parent is not expanded as like in the picture below).

Is it possible to hide "Effects" for all the folders / layers or, what would be even cooler, to indicate having them with some small icon (next to layer name / "fx" or something)? Because right now 5 layers with Layer Styles take as much space as 40 layers without them...

Thanks a lot! :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide them, if you click on the triangle icon next to the `fx` icon.

If you want to hide all at once hold down <kbd>alt</kbd> while clicking on the icon.

If you want them off by default, you can go to the list icon in the top right of the layers panel, click on `panel options` and uncheck `expand new effects`.

(I had to guess the translations, since I am on the german version)